# NSInvocation object related error .....Help !

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

NSInvocation: warning: object 0x463fa20 of class '_NSZombie_CFString' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead

*** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x463fa20 of class '_NSZombie_CFString' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort

How to solve this kind of error ? what does it indicates ?

Comment: What line of code caused this error? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

Comment: Did you call this in the main thread?

Comment: on separate class (Delegate class), which is called by background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most possible cause is that you might forgot to retain the NSString somewhere, or over-releasing it.